# MYSQL 5.6 : Select where value is in CSV colum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database (Mysql 5.6) like this :

```
id | value
--------------------------
1  | "value1;value2;value3"
2  | "value4;value5;value6"
```

I'd like to make a request like :

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE 'value5' IS IN value
return --> 2
```

SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5c347

*I cannot change the database schema*

Comment: `Find_in_set` may work... though its generally slow.... `Where find_in_Set('value5',replace(value, ';',',')>0`  Data would be better off normalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LIKE syntax, but use it like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE
    value LIKE 'value5;%' OR
    value LIKE '%;value5' OR
    value LIKE '%;value5;%' OR
    value LIKE 'value5';
```

This is a dirty solution, and not possible to index, but should fit your needs (On a smallish table in a reasonable amount of time)

Another solution (If you're sure your values don't contain commas):

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET('value5', REPLACE(value, ';', ',')
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the values are different, you might be able to use LIKE:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE value LIKE '%value5%';
```

Just keep in mind that it won't work in case you have some value that contains the other, like

```
value2;value3;value56
```

Or use a RegExp, like this:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE value REGEXP '(^|[^a-z0-9])value5([^a-z0-9]|$)'
```

Comment: Silly me ! Didn't even thought of using regex ! I was too focused on splitting. I think I can overcome the problem with something like (do'nt know sql regex synthax) `"^value5$||^%value5;%||;value5$"`. What do you think ?

Comment: @IggY Well, you could also use regexp, like this: `SELECT id FROM table WHERE value REGEXP '(^|[^a-z0-9])value5([^a-z0-9]|$)`